# How can I store a shared preference without having a preferences screen etc

Tags: android

I just want to store username and password when a checkbox is clicked. I don't need a context menu and  a preference screen. how can I have a simple method that store those values in my login class?

Comment: [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) with a [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have to use the preferences screen .

here's a sample code (should be run in an activity , service , or whatever context that you have ) :

reading:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("settings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userName=sharedPreferences.getString("userName",null);
String password=sharedPreferences.getString("password",null);
```

writing:

```
Editor editor=getSharedPreferences("settings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("userName",userName);
editor.putString("password",password);
editor.commit()
```

for the "settings" , i suggest using a unique constant string , like the activity's class name . of course you can use anything you wish ...

Answer (score 5):

to store a string value(for example) in the application shared prefs, from any activity derived class:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PEFS_DESIRED_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putString("password", mPasswordValue).commit();
```

to load it next time:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PEFS_DESIRED_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
mPasswordValue = prefs.getString("password", DEFAULT_VALUE_IF_NOT_EXISTS);
```